# How do I Fill a Subdivided / Smoothed Barrel's cutout With 2 Sided Right Angle Face?

Tags: modeling

I have a barrel that I need to make a shelf in. I need to fill the cutout section. The barrel has already been subdivided and smoothed. Preferably with a right angle corner fill.. or curved corner might work. The blender file is located here: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/Templeton Any pearls of wisdom are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this in several stages, to make sure the topology stays nice and works well with both the subdivision modifier and the smooth shading.

Start with filling the horizontal surface. Connect the two verts that delimit this part and join them into an edge with <kbd>F</kbd>.
Subdivide this edge 5 times with <kbd>W</kbd> --> Subdivide --> crank up to 5 in the tools panel.
Then fill this surface with a grid fill (Spacebar menu --> Grid fill), using 6 spans and an offset of 6.
[image: Horizontal surface]

Repeat this process for the upper cap (6 spans and an offset of 3 for the grid fill this time):
[image: Stage2]

Add a loopcut in the perimeter of the barrel, at the same height as the edge we started with in the last step. Create faces for the rim at the left and right by selecting 4 verts and filling a face (<kbd>F</kbd>).

[image: Stage3]

Now you can fill the last hole with another grid (see span and offset params in gif below). Add another cut by selecting the two verts near the bottom and creating and edge with join <kbd>J</kbd>, to maintain a nice flow of vertical loops. Select the loop above which is distorted due to the current topology, and straighten it this way: make the leftmost vertex, that representing the desired height for all the verts, active by deslecting and reselecting it (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd>). Change the pivot point to active element, then scale all verts to 0 on the Z axis (<kbd>S</kbd> --> <kbd>Z</kbd> --> <kbd>0</kbd>).

[image: Stage4]

Now, if you like, you can add more loopcuts or increase the crease value to control the curvature of the subdivided surface.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, those are two separate object, the barrel has a top cover.
then, you can fill that "hole", by

1. disabling the subsuface modifier
2. in edit mode, activate edge selection (CTRL-TAB)
3. then select two opposite edges, facing each other from both sides
4. press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face: this will create a face crossing the hole.
5. repeat until the hole is filled.

[image]

then you will get something like this
[image]

from here, you can re-enable the subsurf to find out that he surface just created is too smoothed, but selecting edges and using SHIFT-E (edge crease) you can get those edge sharp, as much as the topology allows you ( I tried and had mixed results, I feel something should be changed in the barrel to make that filled part completely flat with the subsurf enabled...)

but you asked for even just some "pearl of wisdom"... :D
here they are...